# Set a GMT on a countdown script

Tags: javascript, timer, timezone, countdown

How can I set a GMT to date.Now()?

```
var countDownDate = getNextDayOfWeek(new Date(),0,21);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toString();
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toString();
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)).toString();
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000).toString();

    // Add 0 when value are < 10
    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0"+hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0"+minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0"+seconds : seconds;

    var grb = jq("#grb");
    // Display the result in the element with id="grb"
    grb.html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s");

    // If the count down is finished, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        var one_hour = -60 * -60 * -1000;
        if(distance < one_hour){

            grb.html("GRB is finished!");
        }else{
            grb.html("GRB is open!");
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

});

It keeps using the time of your computer, and I want to use a timezone to be stored everytime.

I have tried TimeZoneOffset, didn't worked, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does *getNextDayOfWeek* return? Using *setInterval* with an interval of 1000 does not guarantee that it will run at precisely one second intervals. Days are not all 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed. The *getTimezoneOffset* method returns the timezone offset based on host system settings, it is not associated with a Date object. Dates don't have a timezone offset property, you can't set it.

Comment: @Blutengel - There's nothing in your code here that is working with local time.  Please show the implementation of `getNextDayOfWeek`.  Your concern could probably be addressed there.

Answer (score -1):

please see this

```
var now = new Date();
var nowUTC = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
var distance = end - nowUTC;
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful. You should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Comment: Hello, it is not working as it is not showing GMT+8.